# A man had a friend send me cash to convert to Bitcoin to send him to pay for medical expenses

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

I am an underwater pipeline engineer and I run a small contracting firm in Dallas. We are contracted or hired for services like full installation and maintenance of heavy duty pipeline offshore and onshore. We also render services like oil supply/drilling. By the grace of God, I have worked as a consultant and independent contractor to several notable companies and I have visited several countries due to the nature of my job. I love my job, it's risky and dangerous but highly profitable.

I have been talking to a man from TX for several months who told me that he was a private contractor. He said that he was born in the US to parents who immigrated from Norway and then returned to Norway due to his father accepting a job there when work in his profession was scarce. He has a Norwegian accent since he has lived there for most of his life but he speaks fluent English with only a mild accent. He also writes with very little error.

About 2 months in he went to Poland for a contracted job for Marathon Oil but is now in a Polish hospital due to a knee injury sustained from falling down a flight of stairs. He said his bank account is locked because when he tried to access it from a computer on the rig to purchase additional equipment for the job, due to a poor internet connection, the transaction did not go through and the bank thought someone was trying to hack his account. They will not unlock his account unless he personally goes to the bank in Dallas so that his account can be unlocked. He had a friend send me cash so I can send Bitcoin to him to pay for surgery.

I received the cash yesterday in a US Priority mail envelope. He sent $9,000 in $100 dollar bills. I have checked it with a counterfeit pen and all are good.

Note that the cash is about the same amount I have previously sent to him for assistance in the form of gift cards and bitcoin (approximately $9,000). Now he is requesting that I send him that $9K in bitcoin again.

What will happen if I keep the cash for reimbursement to myself as I am questioning the whole story at this point?

Comment: Don't even really need to read the whole post, this is obviously a scam.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you “have been talking to” him for months, you don’t actually mean face-to-face talking, right? You only know the person online?

Comment: Welcome to the money laundering business, where you receive money in cash from someone you don't know, and send it on by an untraceable means to somebody else.

Comment: Also, while I don't have any experience with the Polish healthcare system, I find it fairly unlikely that a hospital in Poland would demand payment in Bitcoins instead of more traditional means. (Setting aside the fact that he would have to be insured to work there in the first place, thus no payment would have been necessary.)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "He had a friend send me cash..." You have physical cash in hand, and you can take it to the bank and deposit it? How much cash is it, and are you sure it is not counterfeit?

Comment: To the DVers, this question may be different than most, as OP claims to have received **cash**. That would be highly unusual compared to nearly all the other questions which almost always involve reversible or stolen account **electronic funds transfer**.

Comment: @TTT Highly unusual for a scam, perfectly usual for money laundering though. :)

Comment: @TooTea not really. Money laundering works **much** better when both people are in on it. It's too risky to hand over a lot of cash to a stranger and expect them to just follow through with the arrangement, all the while lying to them about it. There are plenty of criminals willing to money launder for profit that you wouldn't need to hope a non-criminal minded stranger will follow through.

Comment: When you say the friend in NY sent you money, do you man he mailed you greenbacks, mailed a check, or transferred money to you? Did you ask why the friend did not just send the Bitcoin to Poland?

Comment: He sent greenbacks $9000 in $100's. I have checked it with a counterfeit pen and all are marking as good.

Comment: I asked the same question about insurance, but he said since he is a self-employed contractor, he isn't required to carry insurance on himself - just the job.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld When you said, "The cash is about the same amount I have sent to him for assistance." you mean you already sent the bitcoin? Did you already deposit the cash and use those funds to send the bitcoin or did you use your own money and haven't deposited the cash yet? If you didn't deposit yet, did you receive the cash before you sent the bitcoin or after?

Comment: I just received the priority envelope of cash yesterday. I have not purchased any bitcoin with it nor have I deposited any of it. It is cash, in a priority envelope only at this point.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld Got it. So what did you mean by "same amount I have sent to him for assistance"?

Comment: I have sent gift cards and bitcoin with my own funds to help him out. All from my own pocket.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld OK. So in the past you've previously sent him approx $9K in gift cards and bitcoin, and now you've received $9K in (presumably real) cash which approximately makes you whole right now. How much is he now asking you to send him in bitcoin to help him out again for the medical bills?

Comment: He want's me to send the whole $9000. He knows fees will come off of it and that I can't send the total all in one day as the coinstar kiosk at the local grocery store has a $2500 limit per 24hrs.

Comment: OK. I'm going to take a stab at updating the question with these new details.

Comment: Yes, the cash would make me whole at this point, give or take a few dollars.

Comment: Something fishy about this post. My gut tells me OP is setting the stage to point to a question like this for his own scam victims. This post may be part of the scam itself. Voting to close on that basis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be written in a way to give credence to an obvious scam; it is not clear what the intent of the post is for except to troll / be used as 'verification' for scam victims down the road.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld What does coinstar have to do with anything you are asking about here? The normal way to convert physical currency into electronic currency is to go to a bank and deposit it.

Comment: I agree with @TTT that this question is different from the plethora of sugar daddy scam questions that are frequently asked.  So, not downvoting nor am I voting to close the question.

Comment: @BobBaerker great edit! I missed the friend/man detail you highlight.

Comment: This is not a scam artist trolling. This is a real life situation that I am currently looking for advice about as I want to make sure I am clear on what I can and cannot do with the cash. The last thing I want or need is a run in with the law. I see a way out of the debt caused by my own ignorance, but at the same time want to be legal about everything.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld Well, it's definitely not legal to just unilaterally decide this money belongs to you now.

Answer (score 4):

He sends you bitcoin, and you send him money - that's a scam. There is nothing else that I need to read, it's a scam, so you are going to lose any money you spend on bitcoin.

If he actually sends cash (bank notes), then it is most likely drug money that needs to be cleaned, and you risk going to jail.

On the other hand, if you just keep the cash, there is a 0.0001% chance that you rob a sick man, and a 99.9999% chance that there are now some serious criminals who are very, very unhappy with you. Not the situation that I would want to be in.

Comment: Looks like you got your first sentence the wrong way round. He sends money, OP turns that into bitcoins.

Comment: Correct. He had a friend from NY state send me money to convert to Bitcoin so I can send the bitcoin to Poland.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld Just curious, any explanation in particular why said friend couldn't do the conversion to Bitcoin on their own?

Comment: He's 74 yrs old and doesn't understand modern technology.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld how did the friend send you money? Was the money electronic funds transfer or was it physical cash sent to you in a package or envelope?

Comment: Physical cash via priority mail to my PO Box

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld If he doesn't know how to use bitcoin, why does he want bitcoin? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The friend that sent me the cash doesn't know how to use bitcoin. The person I would be sending the bitcoin to does. There are 2 different people in this. The older man who sent the cash to me who doesn't understand technology and the man I have been talking for several months that is currently in Poland asking me to purchase the bitcoin for him.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fascinating situation, and I'm reluctant to give advice here. I'll stick to the facts which may guide a proper course of action.

- **The man is lying to you.** There is no question about this. There are way too many things that don't make sense, and what kind of crazy coincidence would it be that the most common setup for a scam *actually happened* in this case?
- **This does not appear to be a *scam*.** Normally, people on the internet attempt to befriend you, and then they make up some story (which is pretty much identical to the story you were given), and they pretend to send you money and have you send it back to them in another format. In the normal case though, the money they send you is some form of electronic transfer which ends up getting reversed because it's fake, or from a stolen bank account. But by the time the transfer is reversed you would have already sent the scammer funds in a non-reversible format (such as bitcoin, gift cards, etc). But this situation differs in that you were sent **cash**, and from your preliminary testing it appears to not be counterfeit. This is incredibly unusual. Note it could still be a scam, if the money does turn out to be counterfeit, or if you never hear from the person again you will be out the $9K, but only because you have already given him $9K up to this point.
- **This seems like money laundering!** On this forum many people throw that term around like it happens all the time. But money laundering rarely happens without both parties being in on it, and without transferring **cash** around. Nearly every question on this forum where people claim it's money laundering is centered around the electronic transfer, not **cash**. The reason money laundering is so rare without both parties being in on it is exactly because of what you are faced with right now. You have the option of keeping the cash instead of passing it on, and if it's true money laundering the criminal is out that money. Criminals generally do not risk allowing strangers to so easily steal from them. But once again, your situation is different because at this moment, the criminal has reimbursed you for money you already gave them. In other words, it's likely you already money laundered the $9K if you keep the cash and don't convert it and pay it back. That's some high level of trust you've earned from a criminal!

As for what to do, you're in a bad place no matter what happens, but I think you need some more info to know how bad. I see two possibilities at this point:

1. **The cash is counterfeit, but good enough to pass your pen test.** IMHO, this is the better of the two scenarios, because it means you simply got scammed out of $9K, and you can turn the cash over to the FBI and let them handle it.
2. **The cash is real.** In this case it's highly likely to be money laundering, which you unknowingly participated in, until now. If you deposit it, you are knowingly depositing presumably dirty money. Worse, there is a criminal who knows where you live and is expecting you to send him $9K more. What happens when he doesn't get it?

If it were me, I'd start by speaking to an attorney who specializes in this. Make sure the conversation will stay confidential. (On TV and in movies they always *retain* an attorney before talking, like paying $1 first for example, but I don't know if that's actually how it works.) You need someone who specializes in this matter who you can be honest with about exactly what happened. I would do this ASAP before contacting the person again, and before doing anything with the money. I doubt you are in criminal trouble based on the facts you laid out, but you want to make sure that remains true based on your next course of action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems like the most sensible advice so far. I just need to figure out what kind of lawyer to talk to.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld I would search for money laundering defense attorneys in your area.

Comment: "The cash is counterfeit, but good enough to pass your pen test. " This is my take too. A flaw in the pen can be used by criminals to make fake notes seem to be OK. First, certain solutions can be used to invisibly coat fake notes so they "pass" the pen test. Another thing they can do is bleach lower denomination notes and re-print them to look like high denomination notes. The paper, being genuine banknote material, passes the pen test, but the notes will fail a proper test such as used by a bank.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your comments. I spoke to an attorney via phone today - very kind and informative. I have an appointment with a police officer tomorrow at the local department. The attorney advised me to do so. That way it is all taken care of above board.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld Great to hear. Good luck! Please feel free to update us in the future when you know more.

Comment: Update - the police officer called me this evening as he has a schedule change and will not be available tomorrow. He asked that I take the cash to my local bank and have them verify if the money is counterfeit or real. Them go to the station to see another officer that he has filled in on my situation. They want to file a report for their records. I will post an update once all is taken care of tomorrow. Once again thank you everyone!

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld so... how does your story end?

Answer (score -2):

Frank Abignale (well known con-artist) has a video on the two big red flags of scams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d526OqZX_LI

Flag #1: he needs money **now**.

Comment: No, he has been waiting for a week or 2 for his friend to gather the funds for him. Now that the funds are with me, he wants me to send the funds to him. It will take a few days to get that much to him, so yes, he wants to pay the hospital, but know it is a process for everything to get to him.

Comment: Just a slight variation on the scam.  After all, the hospital might not let his friend out, or something.

Comment: The fact that real cash was sent, makes me lean more towards this being money laundering than scam. (Unless the cash turns out to be counterfeit, but as of right now we don't have any reason to assume that.)

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld your last sentence in that comment seems like you still think the guy is in the hospital. At this point I would not assume that, or anything else he told you, is actually true.

Comment: I said nothing about him being in the hospital now. He needs the money to pay one of the hospital bills. The doctors have not cleared him to fly home yet due to the type of injuries sustained.

Comment: @WhatInTheWorld I meant- in the question you mentioned he's in the hospital now. And in the comment here you said he wants to pay the hospital. My suggestion is that based on everything that has transpired, I would not assume anything he's told you until now is true. (Except maybe for the part where he said he'd send you $9K in cash, which he did.) For example, any chance the guy is not actually in Poland right now? Who's to say he isn't in Africa, or NY, or Dallas sitting in his living room moving money around?

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. I'm just trying to figure out my next move so I am not breaking the law, but might be able to get myself out of the financial mess I have caused myself.